# Codeception - how generate test skeleton for entire class with all methods automatically?

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I have a PHP application with composer using psr-4 autoloader from src folder placed in the root folder.

I also have codeception bootstrapped in the app root folder.

In codeception manual I read that I can use the following command:

`php codecept.phar generate:phpunit unit Classname` to generate a unit test class.

But I want to simply run it like:

`php codecept.phar generate:phpunit unit "SomeVendor\SomeSubSystem\Class"`

for a specific class placed in `src/SomeVendor/SomeSubSystem/Class.php` and I want to generate a test class with all methods like in PHPUnit skeleton generator.

`phpunit-skelgen --test -- "project\Calculator" Calculator.php`

I have absolutely no idea on how make it with codeception, and no information found in codeception manual. Please help.

Comment: I wonder, do you have codecept.phar actually in your root? And from which folder are you trying to initiate it?

Comment: yes, i have. i want to get solution, i am don't know how do it right way, please help with it. Thanks for reply.